# Issue with astunparse module: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to use the ast and astunparse modules in Python to automatically transform a class-based code structure into a class-less structure. I have written a script that traverses the abstract syntax tree (AST) and modifies it accordingly.

However, when I attempt to use astunparse.unparse(tree) to convert the modified AST back into source code, I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 98, in <module>
    transformed_code = transform_code(original_code)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 85, in transform_code
    transformed_code = astunparse.unparse(tree)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\__init__.py", line 13, in unparse 
    Unparser(tree, file=v)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.dispatch(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 66, in dispatch
    meth(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 78, in _Module 
    self.dispatch(stmt)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 66, in dispatch
    meth(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 109, in _ImportFrom
    self.write("." * t.level)
               ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'
```

This error seems to be related to the astunparse module, but I'm having trouble identifying the root cause.

**Code:**

```
import ast
import astunparse

def transform_code(source_code):
    tree = ast.parse(source_code)

    # Store the created functions and dictionaries
    created_functions = []
    created_dicts = []

    def visit_class(node):
        nonlocal created_functions, created_dicts

        class_name = node.name
        functions = []

        for class_node in node.body:
            if isinstance(class_node, ast.FunctionDef):
                functions.append(class_node)

        # Create a function for each method in the class
        for func in functions:
            func_name = f"{class_name}_{func.name}"
            created_functions.append(func_name)
            func_def = ast.FunctionDef(
                name=func_name,
                args=func.args,
                body=func.body,
                decorator_list=[]
            )
            ast.fix_missing_locations(func_def)
            created_functions.append(func_def)

        # Create a dictionary for the class attributes
        dict_name = f"{class_name}_dict"
        created_dicts.append(dict_name)
        dict_assign = ast.Assign(
            targets=[ast.Name(id=dict_name, ctx=ast.Store())],
            value=ast.Call(
                func=ast.Name(id="create_material", ctx=ast.Load()),
                args=[],
                keywords=[],
            ),
        )
        ast.fix_missing_locations(dict_assign)
        created_dicts.append(dict_assign)

        # Replace the class node with function and dictionary references
        return [
            ast.Expr(
                value=ast.Call(
                    func=ast.Attribute(
                        value=ast.Name(id=dict_name, ctx=ast.Load()),
                        attr="update",
                        ctx=ast.Load(),
                    ),
                    args=[],
                    keywords=[
                        ast.keyword(
                            arg=func.name,
                            value=ast.Name(id=f"{class_name}_{func.name}", ctx=ast.Load()),
                        )
                        for func in functions
                    ],
                )
            )
        ]

    # Traverse the AST and replace class nodes
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
            index = tree.body.index(node)
            tree.body[index:index + 1] = visit_class(node)

    # Add imports for the required functions and classes
    imports = [
        ast.Import(names=[ast.alias(name="load_image", asname=None)]),
        ast.Import(names=[ast.alias(name="vec3", asname=None)]),
    ]

    # Insert the created functions and dictionaries at the beginning of the AST
    tree.body = imports + created_functions + created_dicts + tree.body

    # Convert the modified AST back to source code
    transformed_code = astunparse.unparse(tree)

    return transformed_code

# Example usage
original_code = """
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 98, in <module>
    transformed_code = transform_code(original_code)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 85, in transform_code
    transformed_code = astunparse.unparse(tree)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\__init__.py", line 13, in unparse 
    Unparser(tree, file=v)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.dispatch(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 66, in dispatch
    meth(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 78, in _Module 
    self.dispatch(stmt)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 66, in dispatch
    meth(tree)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\astunparse\unparser.py", line 109, in _ImportFrom
    self.write("." * t.level)
               ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'
"""

transformed_code = transform_code(original_code)
print(transformed_code)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you posted the full error traceback message, instead of just the final line.

Comment: Why is the error traceback now also used as a string in the "example usage"?

Comment: Can you print `tree` and `tree.level` before calling `unparse()`, to see if they look reasonable?